# Remove input value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

each time I click on a option his data-type should appear in the input.

But I want if the value is already in the .val of the input should not appear anymore and if I click twice I want to remove the data-type from input.

Here is my Jsfiddle:

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function () {
        var type = $(this).data('type'),
                answer = $('.answer'),
                initial = $('.answer').val();

        $(this).toggleClass('checked');

        if (answer.val().length === 0) {
            answer.val(type);
        } else {
            answer.val(initial + ',' + type);
        }


    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xbwocrf3/

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason to use this special type of "checkbox", and not the native `<input type="checkbox">`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is using jquery map:

```js
$('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('checked');
  //save the values of checked in an array
  var answerValues = $(".checkbox.checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("type");
  }).get();

  //update input text with this values
  $(".answer").val(answerValues);
});
```

```css
.checkbox.checked {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="answer" />

<div class="checkbox" data-type="1">Option #1</div>
<div class="checkbox" data-type="2">Option #2</div>
<div class="checkbox" data-type="3">Option #3</div>
<div class="checkbox" data-type="4">Option #4</div>
```

Comment: Pretty much the same to [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbwocrf3/4/). By the way, `return $(this).attr("data-type");` can be `return $(this).data("type");`

Comment: There is no differnce in this situation, but `.data('type')` is a little shorter.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, what if I have multiple inputs http://jsfiddle.net/xbwocrf3/7/ like this? Why is adding the inital values to the second input?

Comment: You can go this way [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zs23k7v/). Add to the selector a second argument(provides the context in which to search the element matched by the first selector).

Comment: And [my version](http://jsfiddle.net/xbwocrf3/10/) of the same, but without `$('.wrap').each`.

Answer (score 0):

[please check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbwocrf3/13/)

```
    $('.checkbox').on('click', function () {

    $(this).toggleClass('checked');

    var typen = '';
    $(".checkbox").each(function () {
        var type = $(this).data('type');
        if ($(this).hasClass('checkbox checked')) {
            typen = typen + ',' + type;
        }

    });

    if (typen.length > 0) {
        typen = typen.substring(1, typen.length);
    }

    $('.answer').val(typen);

});
```

Comment: Have you checked your own fiddle? First of all, there is `$('.answer').val();` instead of `$('.answer').val('');` in fiddle. Secondly, the idea is to show all selected options, not only last one. And finally it will be better to save `$('.answer')` in variable (`answer`) in the very beginning of code and to use variable instead of multiple same selections.

Answer (score 0):

Do another check before adding the value there:

```js
$('.checkbox').on('click', function () {
    var type = $(this).data('type'),
        answer = $('.answer'),
        initial = $('.answer').val();

    $(this).toggleClass('checked');

    if (answer.val().length === 0) {
        answer.val(type);
    } else if (!new RegExp("\,?" + type + "\,?").test(initial)) {
        answer.val(initial + ',' + type);
    }
});
```

```css
.checkbox.checked {
    border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="answer" />
<div class="checkbox" data-type="1">Option #1</div>
<div class="checkbox" data-type="2">Option #2</div>
<div class="checkbox" data-type="3">Option #3</div>
<div class="checkbox" data-type="4">Option #4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the input has `checked` class:

```
if($(this).hasClass('checked'))
        return;
```

Final:

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('checked'))
        return;//Stop the execution of the function

    var type = $(this).data('type'),
        answer = $('.answer'),
        initial = $('.answer').val();

    $(this).toggleClass('checked');

    if(answer.val().length === 0) {
        answer.val(type);
    } else {
        answer.val(initial +','+ type);                   
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's map function to get the type data from all elements. Then combine using the join function.

http://jsfiddle.net/xbwocrf3/8/

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    var answer = $('.answer');
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    answer.val( $(".checkbox.checked").map(function() {return $(this).data("type")}).get().join(", ") );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, what if I have multiple inputs jsfiddle.net/xbwocrf3/7 like this? Why is adding the inital values to the second input?

Comment: In such a case you need to select the checked items that are children of a certain common parent. That said you could (and should) wrap both the answer and the options in an element and refer to that when querying the selected answers.

Comment: Or refer to everything by parent. This is less clean but still works: http://jsfiddle.net/xbwocrf3/11/

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little cleaner:

http://jsfiddle.net/xbwocrf3/9/ **(link updated, I pasted it wrong before)**

- It uses native checkboxes
- Instead of doing something as hard as trying to remove old values, it rewrites the whole value of the input from scratch
- The items appear always in their natural order

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="answer" />

<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="something" id="something1"/>
<label for="something1">Option #1</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="something" id="something2"/>
    <label for="something2">Option #2</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="something" id="something3"/>
    <label for="something3">Option #3</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="something" id="something4"/>
    <label for="something4">Option #4</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
    border:2px solid green;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var $answer = $(".answer");

    var checked_values = $.map($("input:checked"), function (element){
        return element.value;
    });

    $answer.val(checked_values);       
});
```